# Quiero correr un codigo de grafico turtle en google colab pero a ejercutarlo me suelta un error: TclError: couldn't connect to display ":2.0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colab

Este es el codigo fuente del programa, al ejecutarlo en google colab arroja el error: TclError: couldn't connect to display ":2.0".
He intentado cambiar el numero de Display por 1.0 pero tambien arroja el mismo error.

```py
!apt-get install -y xvfb # Install X Virtual Frame Buffer
import os
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':2.0'
import turtle
def draw_spiral(my_turtle,line_len):
    if line_len>0:
        my_turtle.forward(line_len)
        my_turtle.right(90)
        draw_spiral(my_turtle,line_len - 5)
my_turtle=turtle.Turtle()
my_win=turtle.Screen()
draw_spiral(my_turtle,100)
my_win.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Que yo sepa no puedes hacer eso en Google colab. Deberás crear una pantalla virtual para lograrlo

Comment: Puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49478228)

Comment: Ahí te deje un enlace a una pregunta en el sitio en inglés

Comment: Al implementar dicha solucion me arroja un error, el cual dice lo siguiente: TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1.0"

Comment: Ahora no dispongo de un ordenador para poder ayudarte, recomiendo que actualices tu pregunta agregando el código que haz hecho, adjuntando el enlace y mostrando el error que obtienes. Así tal vez otros puedan ayudarte

Comment: Listo, igualmente gracias por su ayuda.